# How to find and correct outliers in a highly fluctuating data points

Tags: outliers

Assuming I have an array **{5,30,7,8,9,10,1,46,3,4,70,12,13,14,15,16,99,18,19,90}**. How can I separate **{30, 46,70,99,90}** from **{5,7,8,9,10,1,3,4,12,13,15,16,18,19}**?

Actually, my ultimate purpose is to correct all the outliers and restore the array to **{5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}**? (You can see that that the whole array is not rising or falling consistently, but partially so.)

Any hint or direction would be greatlly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not specify any programming language or tool you are using, I will provide an answer in python.

Using st. dev:

```py
import numpy as np

s = np.array([5,30,7,8,9,10,1,46,3,4,70,12,13,14,15,16,99,18,19,90])
s.mean(), s.std() # (24.45, 28.178848450566605)

num_std_dev = 2 # tweak this for your use case
lower_bound = s.mean() - num_std_dev*s.std()
upper_bound = s.mean() + num_std_dev*s.std()

filtered_within_bounds = s[(s > lower_bound) & (s < upper_bound)]
# [ 5, 30,  7,  8,  9, 10,  1, 46,  3,  4, 70, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19]

filtered_outside_bounds = s[(s <= lower_bound) | (s >= upper_bound)]
# [99, 90]
```

Or using quantiles:

```py
import numpy as np

s = np.array([5,30,7,8,9,10,1,46,3,4,70,12,13,14,15,16,99,18,19,90])

lower_q = np.quantile(s, 0.25)
upper_q = np.quantile(s, 0.75)
iqr = upper_q - lower_q

lower_bound = lower_q - 1.5*iqr
upper_bound = upper_q + 1.5*iqr

filtered_within_bounds = s[(s > lower_bound) & (s < upper_bound)]
# [ 5, 30,  7,  8,  9, 10,  1,  3,  4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19]

filtered_outside_bounds = s[(s <= lower_bound) | (s >= upper_bound)]
# [46, 70, 99, 90]
```

Then if you want to clip the values to be within those bounds, you can using the clip function.

```py
s = np.array([5,30,7,8,9,10,1,46,3,4,70,12,13,14,15,16,99,18,19,90])

clipped_s = np.clip(s, a_min=lower_bound, a_max=upper_bound)
# [ 5.  , 30.  ,  7.  ,  8.  ,  9.  , 10.  ,  1.  , 42.75,  3.  ,
#   4.  , 42.75, 12.  , 13.  , 14.  , 15.  , 16.  , 42.75, 18.  ,
#  19.  , 42.75]
```

At the end of the day, you can do anything you want to your sample, but using standard deviations or IQR to handle the outliers will be the most scientific way to decide which values you can safely ignore.